# Python - pip virtualenv wrong root error

Tags: python, pip, installation, virtualenv

Looking through StackOverflow I see that a lot of people have had problems with pip and virtualenv, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific problem.

I am trying to `pip install` in a virtual environment, but whenever I try, it attempts to install in a virtual environment in a different directory, one which I have long since deleted. I cd into `website` but when I run `flask/bin/pip install flipflop` I receive:

```
zsh: flask/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /Users/User/Downloads/lyric_website/flask/bin/py: no such file or directory
```

It's very frustrating!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using OSX Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: Did you try `flask/bin/python3 -m pip install flipflop`??

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, that works thanks!!